# Insert Multiple Rows in Mysql Using Foreach array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to get multiple rows to insert into a mysql table from a form that allows for multiple checkboxes.

This is the form:

```
<input type='submit' name='invite-group' value='Invite To Group'>
<br />
<?php
$query2aac = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE yoozer1='$userdb1a' AND  followaccept='Yes' ORDER BY yoozer2 DESC");

while($row2aac = mysql_fetch_array($query2aac))
{
    $rowid = $row2aac['followid'];
    $yoozer2aac = $row2aac['yoozer2'];
    $yoozer2aacurl = strtolower($yoozer2aac);
    $palurl = '<a href="http://www.bunchofus.com/fanpage/' . $yoozer2aacurl . '">' .    $yoozer2aac . '</a>';
    echo '<input type= "hidden" name = "id[]" value="' . $rowid . '"></input>';
    echo '<input type= "checkbox" name = "friends[]" value="' . $yoozer2aac . '">' . $palurl . '</input><br />';
}   
?>
```

This is the php:

```
if ($submit)
{
    $submit = $_POST['invite-group'];
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d");
    $lowername = strtolower($username);
    $combined = $_POST['friends'];

    foreach ($combined as $username) 
    {
        $insert1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO grprequest VALUES ('','$grpid3','$username','$myuser','$grprights3','$grpactive3')");
    }
}
?>
```

It is inserting one line into the database but not multiple lines. If I echo the username after the foreach, multiple usernames are showing.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: People look tired today... lol

Comment: Please post the output of `var_dump($combined);`

Comment: @Travesty3 array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "yoozpaper" [1]=> string(9) "bunchofus" }

Comment: This is horrible, horrible piece of code. BTW, do you get any errors? Something like `You have an error in your query near...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the sample code you've provided, and the var_dump of `$combined`, I'm not sure why it isn't working for you. But perhaps you could try something like this:

```
$inserts = array();
foreach ($combined as $username)
    $inserts[] = "('','$grpid3','$username','$myuser','$grprights3','$grpactive3')";

$query = "INSERT INTO grprequest VALUES ". implode(", ", $inserts);

echo "query = $query"; // for debugging purposes, remove this once it is working
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

This will perform all of your inserts in one call to the database. I added an `echo` before performing the query so that you can see the exact query that's being performed.

---

One thing that you should definitely note is that it looks like your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. There are hundreds of places you can look to find out more about how to protect yourself, so just search for it. My favorite reference is [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

It also looks like your form is vulnerable to XSS attacks. You select data from the database and insert it directly into HTML, but you should sanitize it first (using something like `htmlspecialchars`).

Comment: Ended up adding two results of the first and one of the other. At least it added multiple. I will try to figure it out from here. Thanks.   query = INSERT INTO grprequest VALUES ('','38','yoozpaper','theSteveDowling','Group','Yes')query = INSERT INTO grprequest VALUES ('','38','yoozpaper','theSteveDowling','Group','Yes'), ('','38','bunchofus','theSteveDowling','Group','Yes')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another variable besides `$username`? Because it seems as you have already used this name based off the `$lowername = strtolower($username);` line.